# how to add QpushButton to every row inside QTablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt4

I need to add a button inside every raw in my table, here is my code :

```
    queue = 1
    test_list = [1,5,51,651,651,651,651,651,651,651,651,651,64,8,54,564,984,654,984,654,84,651,81,651,8,165,18,16,19,88]
    for item in test_list:
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tableWidget)
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("text" + str(item)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("text" + str(item)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("text" + str(item)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 3, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("text" + str(item)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 4, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("text" + str(item)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 5, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(self.button))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 6, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(queue)))
        queue += 1
```

i get this error every time i run the project

`QTableWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPushButton'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#setItem) of `QTableWidget`, look at the method signature of `setItem`:

> QTableWidget.setItem (self, int row, int column, QTableWidgetItem item)

That is why you are getting the error. The method expects a `QTableWidgetItem`, and you are giving it a `QPushButton`.

The method you are looking for is `setCellWidget` ([documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget)).